# How to check whether a excel file is write protected or not in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm developing a sample application in which I have to open an excel file and check whether the file is write protected or not. The code is

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileNameAndPath = @"D:\Sample\Sample1.xls"; 
    // the above excel file is a write protected.

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application a = 
              new  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileNameAndPath))
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass app = 
              new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

        // create the workbook object by opening  the excel file.
        app.Workbooks.Open(fileNameAndPath,0,false,5,"","",true,
                           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                           "\t",false, true, 0,false,true,0);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook w = 
              app.Workbooks.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

        if (w.ReadOnly)
              MessageBox.Show("HI");
        // the above condition is true.
    }

}
```

I would like know whether the file is write protected or not.

Comment: You mean you want to check if the file is readonly?

Comment: no, I want to chek whetehr it is a write protected file or not.

Comment: Distinguish write protected from readonly for me :)

Comment: There two scenarios:

1: You can make a file read only in General tab, and security tab in File properties window.( Right click on the file, and select properties)

2: In excel, you can add a write protection password. Tools menu->OPtions->Security tab. Under this Security tab, "File sharing setting for this work book", which has label called "Password to modify". If you give the password, here, you can open a file in read only mode, will ask for password if you want to modify it.

I want to check whether password is required to modify the file

Answer (score 3):

You can get the FileAttributes an like this:

```
if ((File.GetAttributes(fileNameAndPath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) > 0)
{
    // The file is read-only (i.e. write-protected)
}
```

See for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the file is readonly, then you can check using [`File.GetAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx), like this:

```
if(File.GetAttributes(fileNameAndPath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
{
  //it's readonly :)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at the `HasPassword` property of the `WorkBook` class.

More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.haspassword%28VS.80%29.aspx

Edit: Left my old answer below

Do you mean if the file or the workbook is readonly?

To check if the workbook is readonly the `WorkBook` class has a `ReadOnly` property.

Otherwise, to check the file, look at using the `IO.FileInfo` class in the framework to get out the file attributes, like in the following code:

```
FileInfo fsi = new FileInfo("filepathandname");
if ((fsi.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly )
{
    // it's readonly
}
```

Comment: I tried that, my scenario is a little different. In excel, you can add a write protection password. Tools menu->OPtions->Security tab. Under this Security tab, "File sharing setting for this work book", which has label called "Password to modify". If you give the password, here, you can open a file in read only mode, will ask for password if you want to modify it. I want to check whether password is required to modify the file –

Comment: Has password will come in to picture when the file is password protected and not write protected.

Comment: Well, my final suggestion would then be that maybe it could be the `WriteReserved` property? Otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: I tried that also,  if (w.WriteReserved)  
              MessageBox.Show("HI"); 
but the condition is never true....
Anyways thank you very much for your time and concern

Answer (score 0):

You can check [File.GetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, ReadOnly and Write-protected are the same thing. However, you might be encountering the situation where you are unable to access a file because it is being used by another process. In this case, you try to open it with a FileShare as below:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, 
    FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I agree that Read only and Write protected are same, in general terms. But the scenario in my case is alittle different

Comment: There two scenarios: 1: You can make a file read only in General tab, and security tab in File properties window.( Right click on the file, and select properties) 2: In excel, you can add a write protection password. Tools menu->OPtions->Security tab. Under this Security tab, "File sharing setting for this work book", which has label called "Password to modify". If you give the password, here, you can open a file in read only mode, will ask for password if you want to modify it. I want to check whether password is required to modify the file –

Comment: Oh, ok. In that case, my answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can check protection with

```
activeDocument.ProtectionType
```