# How to Determine If a Word Document Is Read-Only?

Tags: c#, office-interop, readonly

I use Word.Interop to work with Word Document and let user to open a file from hard disk.

Sometimes I get error saying that the file that user has chosen is readonly.

How can I check if a file is readonly or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether a excel file is write protected or not in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826352/how-to-check-whether-a-excel-file-is-write-protected-or-not-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you are actually talking about the File attribute (that can be set via the Windows file properties dialog)? If so, you can use [`FileInfo.IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly.aspx):

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"path\to\file");
if (fileInfo.IsReadOnly)
{
    // do something
}
```

otherwise, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use) if another process is using the file.

Comment: Word documents can be marked read only while the file itself is totally normal.

Comment: the other answer as Shadow Wizard said is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826352/how-to-check-whether-a-excel-file-is-write-protected-or-not-in-c)